# When would you need to call alloc when creating a new object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, allocation

I understand the whole business around reference counting and "owning an object" and that if you allocate an object in Objective-c, it's your responsibility to release it

However when exactly would you need to call alloc on a newly created object? Would it only be to retain the reference after the end of the scope or is there some other reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call alloc in order to allocate the memory for the object.

The typical setup of an object is something like:

```
Object *obj = [[Object alloc] init];
```

The alloc call allocates memory for the object, and the init call initialises it (gives it sensible default values for all attributes/properties).

Some object types come with factory methods, eg

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray array];
```

In this case, the object is initialised and allocated by the single array call.

None of this has anything (directly) to do with reference counting, except that different ownership rules normally apply to the two methods.

Comment: The only time you would **need** to call alloc yourself is if there is no factory method. You can deal with retain counts and stuff either way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding a basic concept. sending alloc to a class will result in creating a new object of that class (not initialized yet) which you own (retain count will be 1).

from your question "when exactly would you need to call alloc on a newly created object?" - 
if the object is newly created it means that someone already allocated it..

if you meant: when do you need to call retain on a newly created object? the answer is if you want to hold it yourself and not rely on whomever allocated it, and might release it sometime.. remember that alloc/new syntax raises the retain count by one, where as other creating methods (like [NSArray array]) return autorelease objects..

in general i would recommend using ARC and not be bothered by these issues..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly a objective-c guy, but I don't think you call `alloc` on any object, you call it on a class to allocate the object and call `init` on the newly allocated object.

You may want to `retain` to retain the reference after the `release` is performed by autorelease pool, if this is your setup. That often happens to the object created using `[NSThing thingWithStuff:stuff]` or some such.